# Is there a format with fixed number of digits in c#?

Tags: c#, string

I mean if I set to 6

```
if I have 123, I would get 123.000
if I have 123.45, I would get 123.450
if I have 123456 I would 123456
if I have 1234567 I would get 1234567
```

In Math there is a name for this though I don't remember.

I can't see it here ?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

My question is for C# NOT JAVA and about using STANDARD in this language if it exists not custom algorithm since some people thumbed down : they seem to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Hi why thumb down ? This is classical math.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738853/java-decimal-format-parse-to-return-double-value-with-specified-number-of-deci

Comment: My question is for C# NOT JAVA and about using STANDARD in this language if it exists not custom algorithm

Comment: Are you sure 1234567 would be represented as 1234567?  Wouldn't it be 1234570 or 1234560, to be consistent?

Comment: No since I don't want to truncate the result of a calculation just get significative numbers.

Comment: @user310291 - If you are limiting yourself to 6 significant digits when some digits are to the right of the decimal point, why are you allowing 7 significant digits when they are all to the left of the decimal point?

Answer (score 2):

[The "#" Custom Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

[Or just do it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642642/c-sharp-string-formatting-double-fixed-width)

Hope it helps, but I still dont get if you just want always 3 decimals or what?